# recharts = bug in the tooltip

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I want to ask about a bug in the recharts tooltip.

I want to display data in tooltip like below image.

[image]

However, when I execute it in my browser, the data in the tooltip instead displays like this.

[image]

Then I console the data in the tooltip, it appears like this

[image]

this is my customTooltip code snippet.

```
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload }) => {
    if (active && payload && payload.length) {
      console.log(payload, "payload");
      return (
        <div className="custom-tooltip w-fit h-fit p-2 m-0 bg-white drop-shadow-xl items-center rounded-xl">
          <p className="label p-0 m-0 text-sm font-bold">{payload[0].value}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return null;
  };
```

Please help me guys, how do I display the tooltip data like in image 1? Thank you.

my code =

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRecoilValue, useSetRecoilState } from "recoil";
import { endDate, startDate } from "../../../../recoil";
import { getHitApiTotal } from "../../../../service/hitapi";
import {
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  ResponsiveContainer,
} from "recharts";
import Img from "../../../../assets/images/dateIcon.png";
import Img2 from "../../../../assets/images/arrow.png";

const CallRequest = () => {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const defEndDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");
  const StartDate = useRecoilValue(startDate);
  const EndDate = useRecoilValue(endDate);
  const setStartDate = useSetRecoilState(startDate);
  const setEndDate = useSetRecoilState(endDate);
  const [dataKey, setDataKey] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const GetData = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await getHitApiTotal(StartDate, EndDate);
        setDataKey(result.data[1]);
        console.log(result.data[1]);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    if (defEndDate !== EndDate) {
      GetData();
    }
  }, [EndDate, StartDate, defEndDate]);

  const hasil = Object.values(
    dataKey.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (acc[curr["@timestamp"].split("T")[0]] == null) {
        acc[curr["@timestamp"].split("T")[0]] = {
          message: curr.message,
          timestamp: curr["@timestamp"].split("T")[0],
          count: 0,
        };
      }
      acc[curr["@timestamp"].split("T")[0]].count++;
      return acc;
    }, [])
  );

  const data = [
    {
      tanggal: hasil.map((item) => item.timestamp),
      hit: hasil.map((item) => item.count),
    },
  ];

  const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload }) => {
    if (active && payload && payload.length) {
      console.log(payload, "payload");
      return (
        <div className="custom-tooltip w-fit h-fit p-2 m-0 bg-white drop-shadow-xl items-center rounded-xl">
          <p className="label p-0 m-0 text-sm font-bold">{payload[0].value}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return null;
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      {openModal === true ? (
        <div className="w-60 bg-white border-[0.5px] rounded-xl p-5 shadow-xl absolute z-50 top-56 right-[70px] text-gray-500">
          <p>Start Date</p>
          <input
            type="date"
            className="accent-gray-500 border-[0.5px] border-gray-500 rounded-xl w-full hover:cursor-pointer"
            onChange={(e) => setStartDate(e.target.value)}
          />
          <p className="mt-5">End Date</p>
          <input
            type="date"
            className="accent-gray-500 border-[0.5px] border-gray-500 rounded-xl w-full hover:cursor-pointer"
            onChange={(e) => setEndDate(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
      <div
        className="flex flex-col mt-5 items-center justify-start w-[73%] h-96 bg-white drop-shadow-md rounded-3xl border px-5"
        onClick={() => setOpenModal(!openModal)}
      >
        <div className="w-full flex flex-row justify-between">
          <p className="mt-5 text-xl">Call Request</p>
          <div
            className="relative flex flex-row bg-white border w-60 mt-5 p-2 rounded-xl items-center justify-between hover:cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => setOpenModal(!openModal)}
          >
            <img className="w-fit h-fit" src={Img} alt="date" />
            <p className="text-sm text-gray-500 lowercase">{`${
              StartDate
                ? new Date(StartDate).toLocaleDateString("en-US")
                : "DD-MM-YYYY"
            } - ${
              EndDate
                ? new Date(EndDate).toLocaleDateString("en-US")
                : "DD-MM-YYYY"
            }`}</p>
            <img className="w-fit h-fit" src={Img2} alt="arrow" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
          <LineChart
            height={300}
            data={data}
            margin={{
              top: 5,
              right: 5,
              left: 0,
              bottom: 10,
            }}
          >
            <CartesianGrid horizontal={false} />
            <XAxis dataKey="tanggal" padding={{ top: 20 }} />
            <YAxis axisLine={false} />
            <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
            <Line
              type="monotone"
              dataKey="hit"
              stroke="#ef4444"
              strokeWidth="3px"
              activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
              dot={{ r: 0 }}
            />
          </LineChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default CallRequest;
```

Comment: ReCharts does have nothing to do with chart.js, please don't add the chart.js tagg

Comment: I thought the notifications were from people who answered my questions, apparently not. just change the tag, no need to answer in the comments column !!

Comment: I didn't answer in the comments, I left a comment since I already removed the tag from this and your previous question and it would be nice if you just did not add them. Thats why I left a comment in the comments section

Comment: your `payload.value[0]` is clearly an array as seen in the logs. and that is the data that is rendered on your chart.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you, I was not able to place the tooltip above the dot, it is working only if you have bar chart, and in line chart need to hover over the line itself to get the coordinates of the dot, but you can use this code to make the tooltip look like in your image (for placement of the tooltip above bar there is an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-position-recharts-53qef

```
import { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, Tooltip, ResponsiveContainer } from 'recharts'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import { useState } from 'react'
import propTypes from 'prop-types'

const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload }) => {
  const topTooltipPath = (width, height, offset, radius) => {
    const left = -width / 2
    const right = width / 2
    const top = -offset - height
    const bottom = -offset
    return `M 0,0
      L ${-offset},${bottom}
      H ${left + radius}
      Q ${left},${bottom} ${left},${bottom - radius}
      V ${top + radius}
      Q ${left},${top} ${left + radius},${top}
      H ${right - radius}
      Q ${right},${top} ${right},${top + radius}
      V ${bottom - radius}
      Q ${right},${bottom} ${right - radius},${bottom}
      H ${offset}
      L 0,0 z`
  }

  if (active) {
    return (
      <svg width={100} height={30} viewBox="0 0 100 30" style={{ overflow: 'visible' }}>
        <path
          d={topTooltipPath(100, 30, 10, 5)}
          fill="white"
          stroke="#eee"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeWidth={3}
        />
        <text x={0} y={-20} textAnchor="middle">
          {payload?.[0]?.value ?? 500}
        </text>
      </svg>
    )
  }
  return null
}
CustomTooltip.propTypes = { active: propTypes.bool, payload: propTypes.array }

const CallRequest = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null)

  const data = [
    {
      tanggal: '2022-01-01',
      hit: 500,
    },
    {
      tanggal: '2022-02-01',
      hit: 1500,
    },
    {
      tanggal: '2022-03-01',
      hit: 3500,
    },
    {
      tanggal: '2022-04-01',
      hit: 300,
    },
  ]

  const renderActiveDot = ({ cx, cy }) => (
    <>
      <line x1={cx} y1={260} x2={cx} y2={cy} stroke={'red'} strokeWidth={2} />
      <circle cx={cx} cy={cy} r={4} stroke="red" fill="red" strokeWidth={2} />
    </>
  )

  return (
    <div style={{ width: 1000, height: 300 }}>
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
        <LineChart
          data={data}
          margin={{
            top: 5,
            right: 5,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 10,
          }}
          onMouseMove={(data) => setPosition({ data: data, show: true })}
        >
          <XAxis
            dataKey="tanggal"
            axisLine={false}
            tickLine={false}
            tickFormatter={(date) => dayjs(date).format('MMM')}
          />
          <YAxis axisLine={false} />
          <Tooltip
            content={<CustomTooltip />}
            cursor={false}
            wrapperStyle={{ outline: 'none', padding: 0 }}
            contentStyle={{ padding: 0 }}
            position={{
              x: position?.data?.activeCoordinate?.x,
              y: position?.data?.activeCoordinate?.y,
            }}
          />
          <Line
            type="monotone"
            dataKey="hit"
            stroke="#ef4444"
            strokeWidth="3px"
            activeDot={renderActiveDot}
            dot={false}
          />
        </LineChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CallRequest
```

Comment: Their bar chart example doesn't really do what it should. When one hovers over the area above the chart, the data of the tooltip changes as expected but the tooltip stays in the wrong position - above the previously hovered bar.

Answer (score 0):

The data array provided to the LineChart component is structured incorrectly.
You would need to produce an array with the following format:

data = [{month: XX, hit: XX}, {month: XX, hit: XX}...]

You can correct using the following:

const data = hasil?.map((item)=> {tanggal: item.timestamp, hit: item.count})

See the [following](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples) as an example.